# error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, nexus, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have some problem about nginx and nexus repository. I have been created new proxy repository and configured the proxy settings to connect nexus repository with ssl. Then, when i try to connetc the nexus repository with ssl i am getting error like this;

**Login did not succeed, error: Error response from daemon: Get "https://mynexusrpository:9443/v2/": error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4u7R.png)

Note: My nginx configuration file is running for docker hosted repository. But not running for docker-proxy repository.

My Nginx Configuration File:

```
server {
        listen 9443 ssl;
        server_name mynexusrpository;
        ssl_certificate /data/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /data/nginx1.key;
        client_max_body_size 640M;
        location / {
        access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker_proxy.log;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8444;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please include the output of curl to the URL. Also verify you are forwarding to the docker registry port.

Comment: to confirm.  Nginx is running on the server which is also running nexus  container on port 8444?  when running nexus container did you expose port 8444.  I think you want to set `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8444`